# Need help for using www.saytex.xyz

Tags: speech

Saytex is used to dictate equation to get in latex...

But I do not get x \times y

Input to SayTex Demo : x times y

Output: x \cdot y

Desired output: x \times y

Anyone help by giving examples or tutorials

If any other better way to dictate equation...can be shared...

Comment: Please add a MWE, the output and the desired output.

Comment: Visit www.saytex.xyz

Comment: That does not answer any of my points.

Comment: It is about speech to latex...

Comment: If you have experience in speech to latex,  you can help...else you can not understand the request made in the question...

Comment: I fear that this problem really has nothing to do with (La)TeX exactly, since your question seems to be about how to "format" your input to SayTeX in a way that this software returns the desired output. You should consult the documentation of SayTeX then. Apart from that, you should at least tell us what you tried to use as input, since this may help others understand better where the problem is

Comment: Yes...Documentation is not clear...so I need input from experienced user...

Comment: @sandu That's, where you are wrong. Many people, who help here, don't have a clue about the packages or specialities they see here, because very often the problem is not located, where the people think, it is. Even if someone has experience with that, your question is far from sufficient. You do not describe, what you did exactly. Your question doesn't meet the minimum standards.

Comment: And with that attitude, you shouldn't expect a lot of help.

Comment: There is no attitude problem here...  I have given MWE in my question.. that can be tried in that website...demo

Comment: All I am able to say is, that SayTeX stores the strings it converts to LaTeX code in different JSON files. In `saytex/saytexsyntax/saytex_dictionary/operators.json` (see [at GitHub](https://github.com/arvid220u/saytex)) it has `{ "saytex": "times", "latex": "\\times" }` which obviously converts "times" to `\times`. However, in `saytex/layers/synonym_standardization_dictionary.json` this is overridden with `{ "from": ["multiplied by", "times"], "to": "centered dot" }`, but I don't know how to disable this single entry.

Comment: @sandu From your post, we can actually only guess that you mean, that if you say "a times b", SayTeX returns `a \cdot b` and not `a \times b`.

Comment: Yes... and I don't get × symbol...

Comment: @jasper-habicht  could you please post your comment  as answer....

Comment: Have you tried "cross"?  In most math, multiplication is `\cdot`, and `\times` is for the cross product.  Although I wouldn't want `xxy` for "x times y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly a (La)TeX question, since it relates to how SayTeX converts your input to LaTeX code an not to (La)TeX functionality directly. Also, I am no expert in Python programming, which is the language in which SayTeX is written.

Be that as it may: SayTeX seems to store the strings it converts to LaTeX code in different JSON files. You can take a look into the full code at the [SayTeX GitHub repository](https://github.com/arvid220u/saytex). In the file `saytex/saytexsyntax/saytex_dictionary/operators.json`, you will find the following (lines 18–21):

```
{ "saytex": "times", "latex": "\\times" },
```

which obviously converts the string `times` to the macro `\times`. However, in the file `saytex/layers/synonym_standardization_dictionary.json`, this entry is overridden with (lines 6–9)

```
{ "from": ["multiplied by", "times"], "to": "centered dot" },
```

I am unsure how to tell SayTeX to ignore this single line of JSON code in a proper way, but you could probably just make a copy of the file `saytex/layers/synonym_standardization_dictionary.json`, delete the relevant lines and replace the original file with the edited one (while storing the original in a safe place in case you want to restore the original setting). For this, you need to look for the relevant file in your local Python installation (for Windows, it may be somewhere similar to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\saytex\layers\synonym_standardization_dictionary.json`).

I never tested this exhaustively, and I cannot guarantee that it works properly, but this is probably a way to go. Sadly, as you already stated, the SayTeX documentation is a bit tight-lipped as to how to do such customisation things. Note that the edited file may be overridden and therefore the functionality restored to default if you try to update the SayTeX package (for example using PIP).